# Two finger swipe on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using a UITableView in my application to show a set of images under each section in a UITableView.I have a requirement which makes the UITableView to scroll to next section if the swipe is done with two fingers.

Can some one help me in making the UITableView respond to two finger swipe.I tried by assigning a swipe gesture with number of touches assigned to two but the table responds to normal traditional scroll.

Can someone suggest a way to implement this.If possible with pieces of code which is well appreciated.

TNQ

Comment: might help http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2

Comment: i already set the number of touches

Answer (score 1):

```
[swipeGesture setCancelsTouchesInView:TRUE];
```

This will make the gesture recognizer swallow the touches.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!